# validar usuario php

Tags: php

muy buenas tengo un problema en la validación de usuario he usuado 3 conexiones distinta y no me sale 
mi problema es que ingreso datos en mysql usuario(aaa) y password(aaa)quedan guardados
[image: my base de dato]

pero cuando lo valido en mi pagina web utilizo un archivo php para validar y cuando pongo los valores usuario(aaa)y password(aaa)
me sale que no hay datos y no puedo ingresar

este es mi codigo php

```
<?php   
$usuario=$_post['usuario'];
$password=$_post['password'];

$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","peyayo18","empresa");

$consulta=("SELECT *FROM login WHERE usuario='$usuario'AND password='$password'");
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

$filas=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($filas>0){
   header("location:/pg/camiones.html");
}
else{
    echo"0";
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

me gustaria que me ayuden por que no se cual seria el problema

Comment: ¿Seguro que está conectando: `if($conexion){ echo "Ok"; }` dime si imprime `Ok`. Escribe las variables `$_POST` en mayúscula, y haz un `var_dump($_POST);` a ver que muestra.

Answer (score 1):

Los datos por flujo post debes llamarlos en **mayuscular**:

```
<?php
echo 'Usuario: '. $_POST["usuario'];
?>
```

Por que si usas minusculas no existiran...

> Como **tip adicional** pasarles un htmlentities() antes de
>   insertarlos, es como parte de las buenas practicas de programación y
>   evitar inyecciones. Si tu decides guardar el pass en "plano", pues
>   cada quien, peor lo recomendable es guardar el HASH resultante.

Respecto a tu **conexión a la Base de Datos**, nunca esta por demás que verifiques el estatus antes de pasar a mandar una consulta.

Y para descartar cualquier errata en el nombre de las variables o saber si existen en el flujo:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias si eso habia sido la falla yo lo tenia en minuscula

Comment: si te sirvio agradeceria tu calificacion, eso me ayudaria :D